# Not able to move view up with keyboard Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have gone through various answers but was unable to move my view up when keyboard is visible. I have a edittext in recyclerview on whose focus keyboard is visible.I want the tv_character_limit text to be moved up when keyboard is visible. I need the character limit text to be shown elevated with a z-index. I have set the windowSoftInputMode to adjustResize for the activity and for the fragment in view pager i have added the java code:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Thank you for help.Below is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rel_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@color/pink">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_post" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_character_limit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:text="@string/character_limit"
        android:textColor="@color/tap_to_type"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: move textview out of frame layout and check.

Comment: I had done that and it didnt worked

Answer (score 0):

use,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in the manifest file for your activity.
 ex :

```
 <activity
        android:name=".View.Activity.yourActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of FrameLayout, use RelativeLayout and when your EditText gets focus, just change the position of TextView by calling the RelativeLayout class method similar to layout_above.

Comment: Using layout above will require a view at bottom i just want to align view at bottom of screen but above keyboard when keyboard becomes visible

Comment: The whole layout is squashed when keyboard appears. You can align the TextView to the bottom of the screen and it will be displayed directly above the keyboard. Use align_parentBottom.

Comment: Pankaj I have also tried align parent bottom but using that my view neither appears above keyboard nor its shown with a z index or elevation